# Syntax error near 'SELECT'

Tags: sql, procedure, sqlanywhere

"Syntax error near 'SELECT' on line 9"

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE "DBA"."ultimaDataMigracao"()
RESULT( ultimaData TIMESTAMP)  
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FroM migracao_controlo) THEN
        SELECT max(DataMigracao)
        From migracao_controlo;
    ELSE    
        INSERT INTO migracao_controlo (Id, DataMigracao) VALUES ('1','2000-01-01 00:00:00')
        SELECT max(DataMigracao)
        From migracao_controlo;   
    END IF 
END
```

I'm trying to select the biggest timestamp in a table, but it there is none i want to insert "2000-01-01 00:00:00", and then select it.

Can someone please help? i'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: I think you need a `Begin` and `End` around the `Else` part. There is more than 1 statement.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to add a semicolon (`;`) after the `INSERT` statement to make sure it is seen as a separate statement from the `SELECT` by the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "DBA"."ultimaDataMigracao"()
RESULT( ultimaData TIMESTAMP)  
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FroM migracao_controlo) THEN
        SELECT max(DataMigracao)
        From migracao_controlo;
    ELSE    
        INSERT INTO migracao_controlo (Id, DataMigracao)
        SELECT 1, nvl(max(DataMigracao),to_date('01012000','DDMMYYYY'))
        From migracao_controlo;   
    END IF 
END
```

nvl return the second parameter if the first is null.

see here : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp